# symlink to executable doesn't launch application, error: <symlink> doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash

I have a symlink to an executable, which I've created as follows:

```
$ ln -s /home/x/app/wps_office/wps
```

If on the commandline I type:

```
$ /home/x/app/wps_office/wps
```

Then my application launches correctly, but if I try to launch my application through the symlink, then I get the following error:

```
$ wps
wps does not exist!
```

Just to make sure if the symlink is correct;

```
$ readlink wps
/home/x/app/wps_office/wps
```

The folder /home/x/bin is where I've created the symlink, this folder is included in my $PATH variable.

I don't see what is going wrong here, why doesn't my application execute when I use the symlink?

Quick update;

I've just quickly looked trough the contents of the file where the symlink is pointing to, it looks like the message `wps does not exist` is actually coming from the application, meaning the symlink is actually correct. I don't know the exact reason why, as I find it strange that everything works correctly when I don't use the symlink. I need to look more thorougly to the code to find that out.

The code of the file where the symlink is pointing to:

```
#!/bin/bash

gOpt=
gTemplateExt=("wpt" "dot" "dotx")
gBinPath=$(dirname "$0")
if [ -d "${gBinPath}/office6" ]; then
    gInstallPath=${gBinPath}
else
    gInstallPath=/opt/kingsoft/wps-office
fi
gApp=wps

function parse_arg()
{
    if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
        ext="${1##*.}"
        if [ "" = "${ext}" ] ; then
            return 0
        fi

        for i in ${gTemplateExt}
        do
            if [ "${ext}" = "${i}" ] ; then
                gOpt=-t
            fi
        done
    fi
}

function run()
{
    oldPwd="${PWD}"
    if [ -e "${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp}" ] ; then
        if [ -d /usr/lib32/gtk-2.0 ]; then
            export GTK_PATH=/usr/lib32/gtk-2.0
        fi
        ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOpt} "$@" || ${gBinPath}/wps_error_check.sh ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp}
    else
        echo "${gApp} does not exist!"
    fi
}

function main()
{
    parse_arg "$@"
    run "$@"
}

main "$@"
```

Note the line where it says `echo "${gApp} does not exist!"`, this is where my error is coming from.

Comment: do you have this folder in your PATH? if  not run `$ ./wps`

Comment: Yes it is in my $PATH, I've updated my question with that info.

Comment: What are the permissions on the symlink?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx  1 x x are the permissions of the symlink, my username is x

Comment: `strace wps` or `strace -e execve wps` must help find problem. What it writes?

Comment: It appears to pick up the directory where you're starting from as the gBinPath, which is obviously not correct.  At least that's what it looks like.  Try just adding the wps bin path to your PATH, and skip the symlink?

Comment: @roelofs, that is indeed the correct, the solution is acutualy more simple, I can simply create a symlink to `/home/x/app/wps_office/office6/wps` which is the application that is actually being launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

`gInstallPath=/opt/kingsoft/wps-office`

in the script to

`gInstallPath=/home/x/app/wps_office`

Answer (score 2):

Commands will only be executed without any path elements if they're part of the shell, or if they're in the PATH environment variable.  Try
    ./wps
in the directory where the symlink is.  Also confirm that the permissions are correct.

Comment: If I type ./wps in the directory of the symlink, then i get the same `symlink does not exist` error.

Comment: Maybe try and explicitly link using ln -s /home/x/app/wps_office/wps /home/x/bin/wps

Comment: Ok. I've just tried that, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you do a ls -l of the symlink, as well as the binary being linked to, as well as your PATH viariable, and the output of `which wps`?

Answer (score 0):

The file where the symlink was pointing to, takes the current directory to launch a different file. This is the file actually being launched. The issue can be solved by simply creating a symlink to this file, which means a symlink to `/home/x/app/wps_office/office6/wps`

Another option is to edit the source file itself, as explained by @Pixelchemist. However as it concerns an application which I've downloaded and which I will probably update in the future, I think in this case that is not a preferred option.